# Why is the following statements printing thrice?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

Here is my program:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pid_t child;
    int i=0;

    if( argc < 4 ){
        printf("Usage: %s <num_threads> <test_interval> <no_of_prints>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }  

    // Some program logic goes here

    printf("context - switch \n\nPid\ttid\tNPid\tNtid\tJiffies\n\n");

    syscall(320);       

    child = fork();

    if(child == 0 ) { //in child
        fork();
        fork();
        process();
    }
    else    {
            wait(child);
            //Do some printing here 
    }
```

My output has 3 (and sometimes 2) prints of "context - switch" `printf` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because of `stdio` buffering. In a nutshell, multiple processes (the parent, it children, grandchildren etc) end up with the same buffer and they all write it to the screen when they die. Try:

```
printf("context - switch \n\nPid\ttid\tNPid\tNtid\tJiffies\n\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Or maybe just use `write(2)` instead of `printf`.

Comment: But the printed string ends with a newline (two even), and with normal line-buffered stdout, that should flush the buffer, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Not necessarily, especially if the output is redirected to a non-tty. Anyways, the standard guarantees nothing about flushing the buffer when a \n is reached.

Comment: Yes, that's true, no guarantees. But it would be rather unusual if printing to a tty. I didn't think of a redirect, though.

Comment: but `printf` is called once by the parent

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree, a non-line buffered stdout is peculiar but I remember seeing it at least once on this site.

Comment: @mux Think about what `printf` does. It copies the string to a buffer, right ? What happens with all the memory when `fork` is called ?

Comment: @cnicutar it gets copied and then flushed, it makes perfect sense now, thanks. for the record I tried redirecting output to file and it printed 4 times.